# What is the proper way to define a class when a function is an optional parameter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I have declared a class that accepts a function as optional parameter. When this function parameter is not set, a default class method is used. Otherwise, I use my own function.
My code has the following structure :

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self,msg,foo=None):
        self.msg=msg
        self.foo=foo
        
    def print(self):
        if (self.foo == None):
            self.innerPrint()
        else :
            self.foo(self.msg)
        
    def innerPrint(self):
        print("Inner Print : ",self.msg)
        
def outerPrint(msg):
    print("Outer Print : ",msg)
```

So,

```
myObj1=myClass("Hello")
myObj1.print()
```

prints : *Inner Print :  Hello*

and

```
myObj2=myClass("Hello",outerPrint)
myObj2.print()
```

prints : *Outer Print :  Hello*

Is it the proper way to do that or is it possible to simplify this code ?

Someone has posted an answer that has been removed (It is unfortunate because it helps me).

So this is my new code structure :

```
class myClass:
    def __init__(self,msg,foo=None):
        self.msg=msg
        self.printFoo=(foo or self._innerPrint)
        
    def print(self):
        self.printFoo(self.msg)
        
    def _innerPrint(self,msg):
        print("Inner Print : ",msg)
        
def outerPrint(msg):
    print("Outer Print : ",msg)
```

My class method : *print* has only one line now. Is it a good practise ?

Comment: Can you show how this is intended to be used?

Comment: @scoot Hunter. Ok, I edited my question

Comment: What complexity do you think might be simplified, even if you don't know how to do it?

Comment: @Scott Hunter. I edited my question. The idea is to have the possibility to overload a method of a class with an external function. I hope I am clear.

Comment: @Scott Hunter. When the class is instanciated, if an external function is supllied, this function will be used. Otherwise, an internal method with the same prototype will be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second solution is better, because there is no need to check `self.foo` for every call to your `print` method, It is assigned once in the `__init__` method.

You can also use "properties" for this : (I changed some of your variable names to follow naming conventions)

```py
from functools import partial

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, msg, foo=None):
        self.msg = msg
        self.myprint = foo

    @property
    def myprint(self):
        return self._func

    @myprint.setter
    def myprint(self, fn):
        self._func = partial(fn, self.msg) if fn else self.inner_print

    def inner_print(self):
        print("Inner Print : ", self.msg)


def outer_print(msg):
    print("Outer Print : ", msg)


my_obj1 = MyClass("Hello")
my_obj1.myprint()
print("-----------------------------------")
my_obj1 = MyClass("Hello", outer_print)
my_obj1.myprint()
```

output:

```
Inner Print :  Hello
-----------------------------------
Outer Print :  Hello
```

Once you create an instance of your class, The setter is get called in `self.myprint = foo` line. When your `myprint` returns `self._func`, it is either your `inner_print` function, or the partial function that is created with passed `foo` function.

* I used partial class because I had to. Your `outer_print` function need a parameter.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had a problem with my second solution because the method and the function must have the same prototype. And, as you said, in the first one, there a check every time the method is called but the prototype could be different. Your solution is exactly what I need.